# How to import and use a custom font in a material-ui theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, typography, font-family

I'm trying to import and use the Yellowtail font (from Google Fonts) in my React app in a Material-UI theme.

As far as i know all google fonts are on npm, I've installed it, with the

> npm install typeface-yellowtail --save

command.

I have imported it in App.js, put it in the font-family part of the theme, passed the theme to the MuiThemeProvider, but it does not work. What did I miss?

This is what i have inside of App.js (header contains an AppBar with some grids and body contains only an h1 text for testing)

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Header from './Components/Layouts/Header';
import AppBody from './Components/Layouts/AppBody';
import Footer from './Components/Layouts/Footer'; 
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
import 'typeface-yellowtail';

const theme = createMuiTheme({  
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 
      '"Yellowtail", cursive',
  },
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Header />
        <AppBody />
        <Footer />       
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of installing via npm, you can just first load CSS file.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yellowtail&display=swap');
```

Import this CSS file

```
import './assets/css/yellowtail.css';
```

Now you don't need to use any @font-face. This can be used with font families like normal.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I wanted to avoid this approach, hence i'd like to work with the style settings provided by material-ui.

Comment: and where does `yellowtail.css` come from and what does it contain?

Comment: And how did you do if its a premium purchased .otf files without any CDN ?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing three things:

- Import the npm package *as* something
- Use the `CssBaseline` component
- Add an `override` to the object provided to `createMuiTheme()`

See example:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Header from './Components/Layouts/Header';
import AppBody from './Components/Layouts/AppBody';
import Footer from './Components/Layouts/Footer'; 
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';
import yellowtail from 'typeface-yellowtail';

const theme = createMuiTheme({  
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 
      '"Yellowtail", cursive',
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        '@font-face': [yellowtail],
      },
    },
  },
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Header />
        <AppBody />
        <Footer />       
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Example CodeSandbox (MUI v3): https://codesandbox.io/s/late-pond-gqql4?file=/index.js

Example CodeSandbox (MUI v4): https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-monad-eqwlx?file=/index.js

**Notes**

- `MuiThemeProvider` changed to `ThemeProvider` in the transition from Material-UI v3 to v4. If you are on v4, this is the only change needed - this example code otherwise works on both versions.
- You must wrap text in Material-UI's `Typography` component for the font to be used.

Comment: your code doesn't work.  where is CssBaseLine defined? and what kind of font has no extension (i.e. `typeface-yellowtail`)? and `ThemeProvider` doesn't exist in v4 but `MuiThemeProvider` does

Comment: @ekkis I believe you are mistaken about `ThemeProvider`... See the v4 documentation here: https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/

And see the v3 documentation here: https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/

Comment: @ekkis I somehow didn't get the import for `CssBaseline` in the answer, I have edited it. It is a component provided by Material-UI: https://material-ui.com/api/css-baseline/#cssbaseline-api

`typeface-yellowtail` is an NPM package, not a font file. The OP has installed it using `npm install typeface-yellowtail --save`, per the question.

Answer (score 4):

There is a much easier way of doing this that doesn't require a `.css` file or installing any extra packages.

If your font is available over a CDN like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Yellowtail) then just imported into the root HTML file of your app:

```
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yellowtail&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

Then add one line in the Material-UI theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: { fontFamily: ["Yellowtail", "cursive"].join(",") }
});
```

[**Working codesandbox example with Material-UI v5.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/easy-custom-fonts-in-material-ui-ywhel?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This is vastly easier than many of the other answers on the web that involve installation of packages.

Answer (score 3):

I have define my font in main CSS file(`index.css`)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mikhak';
    src: url(./fonts/mikhak.ttf) format("truetype")
}
```

and then in the `App.tsx` I added `theme`

```
const theme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: 'mikhak, Raleway, Arial',
    }
});
    

ReactDOM.render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App />
    </ThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Note that it is for `Typography` components.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Install your font as a package using @fontsource on npm, i.e:

```
npm i @fontsource/work-sans
```

2. Add to your `_app.js` your import, this makes your package (font) accessible globally

```
const workSans = require('@fontsource/work-sans');
```

3. In your theme modify your typography:

```
...
  typography: {
      fontFamily: 'Work Sans',
    }
...
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Since [@ekkis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709223/ekkis) mentioned I'm adding further details on how to include the Google Font. The following answer assumes you're using Material UI v4.10.1

1. Install the [gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader/) to install Google font.
2. Edit `gatsby-config.js` to include the plugin and the Google font.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins:      [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader",
      options: {
        google: {
          families: ["Domine", "Work Sans", "Happy Monkey", "Merriweather", "Open Sans", "Lato", "Montserrat"]
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

3. To use the font, create a file called `theme.js` in `src/components`

```
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  responsiveFontSizes
} from "@material-ui/core/styles"

let theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
                  "Work Sans",
                  "serif"
                ].join(","),
    fontSize:   18,
  }
})

// To use responsive font sizes, include the following line
theme     = responsiveFontSizes(theme)

export default theme
```

4. Now that you've the `theme` export, you can use it in your components.
5. Import `theme` on to your components. Let's say `<Layout />` is your main component.

```
// src/components/layout.js

/**
 * External
 */
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import {
  ThemeProvider
} from "@material-ui/styles"
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core"

/**
 * Internal
 */
import theme from "./theme"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Typography variant="body1">Hello World!</Typography>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  )
}
```

6. To use Google font in other components, just use

```
<Typography ...>Some Text</Typography>
```

As long as these components use  as their parent, these components will continue to use the Google Font. Hope this helps.

---

**Old Answer:**

Place your text in the `Typography` component to reflect the Google Font you installed via `npm`

```
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core"
```

Assume you have some text in `<AppBody>`

```
<AppBody>
    Hello World!
</AppBody>
```

The above text should now be changed to

```
<AppBody>
    <Typography variant="body1">Hello World!</Typography>
</AppBody>
```

Refer [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/) for the different variants.

Comment: thank you for the additions, which help for those who haven't done this before.  much better!

Comment: Careful! If the client has a slow internet connection, the loaded font will take a while. This method requires a separate HTTP request to Googles CDN. Until the request is completed, the fonts will fallback to a standard font.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to @georgeos answer that a small revision of the proposed solution worked for me:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
    ...
    components: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
            styleOverrides: {
                '@global': {
                    '@font-face': [Inter, Nunito],
                 },
            },
        },
    },
    ...
});
```

I also needed to add the following to the `app.ts` file ([source](https://www.welcomedeveloper.com/react-mui-theme#:%7E:text=As%20a%20quick%20advice%2C%20it%27s%20a%20good%20idea%20to%20include%20a%20CssBaseline%20component%20below%20the%20theme%20provider.%20It%20will%20make%20sure%20that%20all%20the%20styles%20in%20the%20app%20are%20applied%20correctly.)):

```
function App(){
    ...
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline enableColorScheme /> <---
        ...
        </ThemeProvider>);
    ...
}
```